# How can I add a row upon clicking a button for my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button at the bottom of my table. I have been messing around with java script, but Im confused on how I would add the correct amount of cells in each row upon clicking my button.

Also, is there a way to add a row, while it also adding a new set of buttons at the end of each row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `insertRow()` method, this creates an empty `<tr>` element and adds it to a table.
The `insertRow()` method inserts the new row(s) at the specified index in the table.
Note: A `<tr>` element must contain one or more `<th>` or `<td>` elements.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the information, this is what you need. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction();" title="addRow" class="btn btn-info" id="row">Add Row</a> 
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var table = document.getElementById("data-table");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(-1);

        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
        cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL4";
        cell5.innerHTML = "NEW CELL5";
        cell6.innerHTML = "NEW CELL6";

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: how would I go about adding my button in cell 6?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using jQuery if you go in that way you could use something like:

```
 $('#addRow').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();          
var $tr = $('<tr>').html("<td>cdcs</td><td>csc</td><td>cscs</td><td>cscs</td><td>cscs</td>");
          var $tdButtons = $('<td>').html('<button>Compress</button><a href="#">Compress</a><a href="#">Download</a><a href="#">Delete</a>');
          $tr.append($tdButtons);
          $('#data-table').append($tr);
        });
```

and the link add row must be something like

```
<a href='#' id="addRow">Add Row</a>
```